# Getting a PhD in Classics/Ancient History with an MA in Modern Lit

Tags: phd, changing-fields, second-degree, humanities

I'm getting an MA in Italian Literature but, writing my thesis on contemporary fiction, I realized that it's not really what I want to specialize in.
I would like to switch to Classics/Ancient History. Do you think it is possible to get a PhD with my background? Or should I get a second MA in the new field?
One third of my undergraduate studies were in Classics (both Latin and Greek), but it's been a couple of years since I looked at that stuff from an academic point of view, and my Greek is a little rusty. I know what my broad area of interest is, but I still need to check the academic literature in the field. It's hard to ask advice to my current professors, since none of them is a classicist.
Thank you in advance.
(PS. I'm from Italy: we start studying Latin and Greek when we're in high school. I'm getting a degree here but I'd love to move to the US for the PhD.)